# how to compare unique identifier with Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, guid

I have a view and entity

```
          var q = from stud in context.CollegePlans                                       
                 where stud .Meta.Active == true &&
                stud .CreatedBy_Id == user.Id
                select stud ;

        var k = from nv in context.vw_Year_Plans 
                 where ( nv.StudentId == q.Where( p => p.Section.StudentId))
                select nv;
```

studenId is Guid in both view and in entity..when i do the above it says cannot implictly convert system.Guid ? to bool ..how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression evaluated by `Where` needs to evaluate to a boolean value.

```
where ( nv.StudentId = q.Where( p => p.Section.StudentId))
```

In this case, you have given it a `Guid`.  That is where the error is coming from.  I think you would have problems with that line even if the `Where` predicate was valid.  From the looks of it, you want to want all of the `StudentId`s in `context.vw_Year_Plans` that are also in `q`.

A simple way to do that is to create an intermediate collection of the ids in `q` for comparison purposes.

```
var temp = q.Select(a => a.Section.StudentId);
```

Then see if each `StudentId` is also in `context.vw_Year_Plans`

```
var k = from nv in context.vw_Year_Plans
        where (temp.Contains(nv.StudentId)) 
        select nv;
```

There are better ways to solve this issue, but this should get you going.

**EDIT**

You mentioned using `join` in your comment. I haven't tested either of these solutions but this should be what you need.  If you are still having problems, update your question with more specific details on the issues you are facing.

```
var k = from nv in context.vw_Year_Plans
        join p in q on nv.StudentId equals p.Section.StudentId  
        select nv;
```

Comment: so how to solve this ? I think Join work for this but how to do that ?

Comment: Yes, join can work in this case also.  Are you having a problem with the syntax?